# why does explicit bit shifting arithmetic result in a bigger .s file?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, micro-optimization, machine-code

I'm not a trained computer scientist, so I don't know all or most details regarding compilation etc, but I've always thought that my c programs are compiled into machine code which I can view with the -S flag using gcc.

I also thought that the closer my code resembled machine code, the faster the computer could execute it. So I decided to test this.

I wrote two test files to compute a simple arithmetic problem.

```
// test1.c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int x = 4243;
    int y = 3235;
    int z = 613*x + 725*y;
    return 0;
}

// test2.c
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    int x = 4243;
    int y = 3235;
    int z = ( ( ( ( ( ( ( x << 3 ) + x ) << 1 ) + x ) << 3 ) + x ) << 2 ) + x + 
      ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( ( y << 2 ) + y ) << 1 ) + y ) << 2 ) + y ) << 2 ) + y ) << 2 ) + y;
    return 0;
}
```

I know I made this example a lot more complex than necessary, but when I tried it with a simpler example, the difference wasn't as clear.

Now, if I compile with gcc -S flag, the machine code is 31 lines for test1.s and 47 lines with test2.s

What are the possible explanations? Is the assumption that fewer lines of machine code mean faster execution flawed? Does the .s file get used for anything before the binary is created? Is my toy test bogus?

Thanks for any insights

Comment: I'm not sure if it affects the 1st hand assembly code, but did you try this using any optimization level?

Comment: Your assumption that resembling machine code == fast is flawed.  Also, not sure why the second one should be more like machine code...

Comment: Yes, your assumption is flawed. 1) instructions do not all take the same amout of time to execute 2) loops can use fewer instructions but repeat them multiple times. Often, more actual written instructions can be faster through a combination of the two. Then the CPU kicks in and does its own stuff.

Comment: First one is using the math processor, second is brute force. PS shorter != faster...

Comment: There exists a `mul` instruction for most machines, so your first example would take 2 `mul`s and one `add`.  Your second example would take as many shifts and adds as you put in there.  Internally, a cpu might be doing shifts and adds, but the `mul` instruction is optimized to do those much faster than could be done "by hand", because many parts of the operation can be done in parallel.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I guess I thought that shifting the bits would be closer to what the machine would do. I guess not...

Comment: test1 resembles reasonable machine code for doing what that program does. test2 does not resemble reasonable machine code for doing what that program does. C++ is pretty close to the metal in the basic operations, so any silly rewrite gets you away from good machine code, not closer.

Comment: Have you thought about **reading** the generated assembly instead of only looking at its number of lines? This would be quite enlightening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used to be a time when CPUs were very simple and unsophisticated, and bit shifting tricks like the one you tried to do above could actually yield better performance than the built-in multiplication instructions of the CPU. (At the expense of program length: a series of shift instructions may and may not be faster than a single multiplication instruction, but it will certainly be longer.)  I believe this held true up until the 80286.

There even used to be a time (remember the Z80, anyone?) when CPUs were so simple that they did not even have built-in multiplication instructions, so we had to invoke routines to multiply numbers, and these routines would of course contain loops that would iterate as many times as the number of bits of the numbers being multiplied, so these bit-shifting tricks would yield much, much better performance back then.  (And again, this would be at the expense of program length: invoking a multiplication routine takes fewer bytes than performing two or more shift operations.)

But nowadays nothing of that sort holds true anymore.  Your (presumably modern) CPU certainly has a built-in multiplication instruction which nominally executes in a very small number of clock cycles, ([small, as in, ***3***](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/299987)) so using it is bound to run faster (and be smaller) than breaking your multiplication down into multiple shift operations, each one of which nominally executes in one clock cycle.

And I say "nominally" because with pre-fetching, pipelining, caching, etc. even the notion that you can know in advance how many clock cycles will be required by any given instruction does not hold true anymore.

So, to cut a long story short: "learn to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb".

Comment: @harold you are right, I looked it up and it turns out that the *latency* for integer multiplication on an intel i7 nowadays is 3 clock cycles. I corrected my answer.

Comment: Instruction latency has nothing to do with the time it needs to execute. On any modern CPU, integer multiplication is 1 every cycle. And you can even do 4 or 8 every cycle with SIMD extensions.

Comment: @ElderBug the time it needs to execute is literally the latency.

Comment: @harold Expect that the latency will never tell you anything about the speed of the instruction. At 3 billions cycles per second, 3 more cycles doesn't really mean anything.

Comment: @ElderBug it does in dependency chains. But that's not even the point. The time *one* instruction takes is by definition its latency. That throughput is important doesn't even enter the picture there.

Comment: @harold I thought that the question was about performance. For what OP is asking, MUL will add like 0 to 1 cycle to his program, while 10 shifts will add like 4 to 5 cycles. Only throughput is important in his question.

Comment: @ElderBug OPs code is just a return (and some constants that are not used) so in that context it's all fairly moot anyway.. But performance is not purely throughput.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74479/discussion-between-harold-and-elderbug).

Answer (score 0):

If you are writing for a CPU that has no multiply instruction (such CPUs do exist), and if you have to compute `613*x + 725*y` many times, then it might be worthwhile writing custom bit-shifting code.

But you would probably have to write it in assembly language to make it faster than the compiler's built-in multiply function.